# Flutter new app can't run when choose Android physical device

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, gradlew

I set up a flutter environment with android.

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fb57da5f94 (2 weeks ago) • 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
Engine • revision caaafc5604
Tools • Dart 2.17.1 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Linux Mint 20.3 5.4.0-113-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
AROFQV5V8LJ device
```

After that, I created a new flutter project and tried to run the project on the physical device shown above (AROFQV5V8LJ, a smartphone), but it didn't work:

```
$ flutter create key_borrow
$ cd key_borrow
$ flutter run
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
   > Could not create service of type GradleInternal using ServicesProvider.createGradleModel().
      > Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
         > Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 644ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,292ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already try everything, including uninstall and reinstall all the environment. Some examples of things that I've already tried:

```
$ ./android/gradlew clean
$ ./android/gradlew build
$ flutter clean
$ flutter pub get
$ flutter run
```

All these commands runs without errors, but when I try to run or build the app (with flutter cli), it always returns the same error above.

Also, I tried to change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` on `./android/app/build.gradle` to version 32 (latest) and still get the same error. Same thing with gradle version: I did some downgrades and nothing changes.

Also I tried to open the project on android studio: it does not show any errors on files, but I still get the same error when I try to run it.

Does anyone have any idea?

#### **Edit**:

Running:

```
$ flutter run -v
[  +56 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +26 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +5 ms] executing: [/home/bbb/app/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false
log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[        ] fb57da5f945d02ef4f98dfd9409a72b7cce74268
[        ] executing: [/home/bbb/app/flutter/] git tag --points-at
fb57da5f945d02ef4f98dfd9409a72b7cce74268
[  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at
fb57da5f945d02ef4f98dfd9409a72b7cce74268
[        ] 3.0.1
[   +7 ms] executing: [/home/bbb/app/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
--symbolic @{u}
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/bbb/app/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +78 ms] executing: [/home/bbb/app/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +50 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[  +55 ms] executing: /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +39 ms] List of devices attached
           ROFQVSJBU845V8LJ       device usb:1-3 product:maltose_global
           model:MK15357EA device:maltose transport_id:3
[   +5 ms] /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ROFQVSJBU845V8LJ
shell getprop
[ +114 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[ +111 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[  +55 ms] Generating
/home/bbb/key_borrow/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPlug
inRegistrant.java
[  +53 ms] ro.hardware = mt6785
[        ] ro.build.characteristics = default
[  +35 ms] Initializing file store
[  +11 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +5 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to
{InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents:
/home/bbb/key_borrow/.dart_tool/package_config_subset}
[  +21 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[        ] Skipping target: _composite
[   +1 ms] complete
[   +5 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on MK15357EA in debug mode...
[   +4 ms] /home/bbb/app/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/home/bbb/app/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/frontend_server.dart.sna
pshot --sdk-root
/home/bbb/app/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/
--incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill
/tmp/flutter_tools.CZNSCU/flutter_tool.GZIXAJ/app.dill --packages
/home/bbb/key_borrow/.dart_tool/package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation
--filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill
build/c075001b96339384a97db4862b8ab8db.cache.dill.track.dill
--enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[  +11 ms] executing: /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
ROFQVSJBU845V8LJ shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +13 ms] <- compile package:key_borrow/main.dart
[ +122 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    06-05 07:06:42.514 W/getprop (17384): type=1400
                    audit(0.0:1285517): avc: denied { map } for
                    path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_fp_prop:s0"
                    dev="tmpfs" ino=1297 scontext=u:r:shell:s0
                    tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_fp_prop:s0 tclass=file
                    permissive=0
[  +15 ms] executing: /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[   +6 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 33.0.2-8557947
           Installed as /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/bbb/app/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[   +6 ms] Building APK
[  +16 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +2 ms] Using gradle from /home/bbb/key_borrow/android/gradlew.
[  +19 ms] executing: /home/bbb/app/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[ +110 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/bbb/app/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840, mixed
           mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: [/home/bbb/key_borrow/android/]
/home/bbb/key_borrow/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=/home/bbb/key_borrow/lib/main.dart
-Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
-Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== -Pdart-obfuscation=false
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +875 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Gradle could not start your build.
[        ] > Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using
ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
[        ]    > Could not create service of type GradleInternal using
ServicesProvider.createGradleModel().
[        ]       > Could not create an instance of type
org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
[        ]          > Could not configure services using
GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[        ] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 726ms
[ +323 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 1,328ms)
[+7853 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[        ] "flutter run" took 9,950ms.
[   +7 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +113 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 111ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Content of `./build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've created this new project multiple times and always get the same error. Also, I tried these suggestions and still I got same error:

```
$ flutter create .
$ flutter run
```

```
$ rm pubspec.lock
$ flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in key_borrow...                       3.8s
$ flutter run
```

#### Changing gradle version

I change the file android/build.gradle: changed `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3`

**Flutter CLI results in same error**.
So, I tried to run gradle and I got this:

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew clean build
*[Several log lines that I ommitted]*
> Task :app:lint FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
  Errors found:
  
  /home/leal/key_borrow/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5: Error: Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.key_borrow.${applicationName}, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingClass]
          android:name="${applicationName}"
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 4 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 53s
```

I also tried to change the variable `distributionUrl` on `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`. I got this:

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.15'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '11.0.15'.
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:253)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:182)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter create .` note that there is a period after create. This will add all missing files. Then try building the app.

Comment: I tried and I get the same error. I've created the project several times before this post, so I don't think it's a problem with the project files unless the flutter CLI is not working as it should.

Comment: Try executing `flutter run --info`

Comment: That does not a valid option for flutter CLI. I could run with -v, If you wish.

Comment: yeah sorry flutter run -v or flutter run --verbose

Comment: I updated the question with the verbose output

Comment: Delete pubspec.lock, run flutter pub get and then try again once

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: In android-> build.gradle you will see dependencies check the version of Gradle. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'`

Comment: Do you see a yellow highlight where the Gradle version is defined? if yes change it to the suggested version.

Comment: I believe this version of gradle are used on older flutter versions. I don't know if this should works here. But I tried it anyway and I updated the question with the results

Comment: Are you able to build an empty project? If yes then add all lib, assets and dependencies to the new project and build. Not sure what's causing the issue

Comment: I don't know if I understood you. This is already a fresh Flutter project, which I created for the purpose of asking this question. How can I create this empty project?

Comment: Did you mean an empty android project?

Comment: Yeah an empty flutter project

Comment: Using `flutter create app` ?? I got the same results.